# Mod_rewrite not working on Ubuntu Server (works locally, though)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu, wamp

I have a local environment working fine.  Pasted a test route in .htaccess and it works as expected (re-routes me to google).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule testpage\.html http://www.google.com [R]
```

I pasted the same thing on my development server (Unbutu 12.04) and it simply gives me a Not Found page.  When I verify it on the devserver by running:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

It says "Module rewrite already enabled".

Edit:  It also appears in the "loaded modules" section of phpinfo() and I have restarted the apache server several times since it was installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely it is because mod_rewrite is enabled but .htaccess files are disabled via

```
AllowOverride None
```

which disables checking .htaccess files (which gives You some performance gains but You have to put Your mod_rewrite code directly in apache configuration files)

Change for Your virtual host to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 2):

For people who don't understand - http://victorpotapov.ru/blog/vkljuchaem_mod_rewrite_v_apache/2013-11-03-61

On this page you can see step by step, that you enter in your terminal on ubuntu

Comment: The relevant content from that page should be added to the answer

Comment: its not about understanding , if you have this problem , follow the [link](http://victorpotapov.ru/blog/vkljuchaem_mod_rewrite_v_apache/2013-11-03-61) on this answer !

Answer (score 2):

**enable mod_rewrite**

Activate the mod_rewrite module with

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

and restart apache

> sudo service apache2 restart

Edit virtual host to use mod rewrite within .htaccess

> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Search for "DocumentRoot /var/www/html" and add the following lines

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Save & Exit CTRL-X, "Y" and Enter

Restart Apache

> sudo service apache2 restart